# SciPy 0.12.0 and Numpy 1.6.1 - numpy.core.multiarray failed to import

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I just installed ArcGIS v10.2 64bit background processing which installs Python 2.7.3 64bit and NumPy 1.6.1.  I installed SciPy 0.12.0 64bit to the same Python installation.

When I opened my Python interpreter I was able to successfully `import arcpy, numpy, and scipy`.  However, when I tried to `import scipy.ndimage` I got an error that said  `numpy.core.multiarray failed to import`.  Everything I have found online related to this error references issues between `scipy` and `numpy` and suggest upgrading to `numpy 1.6.1`.  I'm already at `numpy 1.6.1`.

Any ideas how to deal with this?

Comment: I suspect the issue may be that scipy 0.12.0 is not fully backwards-compatible with numpy 1.6.1 - I suggest you try installing scipy 0.10.1

Comment: Or installing numpy 1.7.1, of course.

Comment: well sure, as long as ArcGIS v10.2 doesn't depend on the older version of numpy

Comment: @ali_m - according to the system requirements on SciPy's website, it just says numpy 1.5.x or above.  I'll give downgrading a shot.

Comment: @ali_m - It looks like downgrading did the trick.  If you want to write an answer I will accept it.

Comment: @cge - Unfortunately, I don't trust ArcGIS 10.2 to work with the latest version of numpy.  In the past, they have always been a little behind the latest version of Python and other Python modules.  Otherwise, thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So it seems that the cause of the error was incompatibility between scipy 0.12.0 and the much older numpy 1.6.1.

There are two ways to fix this - either to upgrade numpy (to ~1.7.1) or to downgrade scipy (to ~0.10.1).

If ArcGIS 10.2 specifically requires Numpy 1.6.1, the easiest option is to downgrade scipy.

Comment: I actually downgraded to scipy 0.11.0 and it worked.  I didn't need to go all the way back to 0.10.1.  Just a minor detail.  Thanks for the help.